# Problem with forward slash "/" in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I always wrote URLs used by AJAX calls in this way:  `"/Home/Save"` with the forward slash in the beginning.  Now this last project is being deployed to a virtual directory on a server.  Thus, these URLs aren't working anymore, because instead of `"example.com/VirtualDir/Home/Save"`, they would point to `"example.com/Home/Save"` which is wrong.  I quickly fixed the problem by removing the first forward slash `"/"` in all occurrences of URLs in my JavaScript. All pages work great, except for one!  When AJAX call happens on the problematic page, the specified URL gets appended to the page URL.  I've spent a few hours yesterday and the whole morning today, and I cannot figure it out.  There is absolutely nothing different about this page comparing to others.  Has anyone had this problem before?  Should I post my code?

EDIT:  After banging my head on the keyboard for another few hours, I ended up implementing the following.  I got an action in a common Controller that returns the result of `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)`, which is your `http://www.mysite.com`.  I render it inside my Layout page into a global JavaScript variable, `_AppPath`.  Then, every AJAX call gets its URL like this:  `_AppPath + '/Controller/Action'`.  This works everywhere and I still don't know what the hack is the problem with that page.  Cheers!

Comment: Does that one page have a wildly different URL?  What makes the one page different, other than this problem?

Comment: @NickAldwin - absolutely nothing.  It's .NET MVC.  All pages that I have are Views with 1 - 3 partial views inside of them.  Urls are all like 'localhost:2244/Home/Display', JavaScript is written to razor section the exactly same way on every View.  There is always a $(document).ready() that calls the Init function from a JS file, which sets click handlers that trigger AJAX calls.  Same everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the Ajax requests so that they instead point to "/VirtualDir/Home/Save"?

If it helps your code, you could have a `path` variable, so that you can easily update the virtual directory path (or remove it) when you deploy it somewhere else. Or your code could read its location via the `window.location.href` property and work out things out from there.

It's not so useful to have paths relative to the current document (i.e. without the / slash prefix) because, as you are observing, some of the pages will then fail their requests, when those pages are at a different point in the site hierarchy. An absolute URL would be the one to go for (i.e. with a / slash prefix).

[UPDATED, based on comments below]

@Dimskiy, it doesn't so much matter that the server-side framework is .NET MVC, or that there are no actual folders for those URLs on the server. The browser will just respond according to the URL structure it sees.

So the things to look for are the URLs in the browser address bar for the different pages, and the URLs of the Ajax requests being made to the server (e.g. look for these in Firebug's "Net" panel). And compare the URLs, looking at the number of folders suggested by each URL.

It doesn't matter if there isn't an actual folder on the server. The browser can't tell, it can only look at the URL structure. If the JavaScript is making a call from a page called "foo" to an Ajax resources at "Home/Save", then the request will be routed to "foo/Home/Save". And if the request is made from page "foo/bar" then it will be routed to "foo/bar/Home/Save". That's a relative path - it's relative to the containing HTML document.

A request to an "absolute" path, say, "/Home/Save" (note the / slash prefix) will always go to the root of the domain, e.g. example.com/Home/Save. But since you need your request to go to the "VirtualDir" virtual directory, then your URL will become "/VirtualDir/Home/Save".

Comment: Thank you for your input!  I've thought of these and similar solutions and if I won't figure this out, I will most definitely go with one of them.  But for the sake of sanity, I want to know why it is 1 page that has this problem when it's not different from any other page.

Comment: Is that one page in a different folder from the rest?  When you specify a url without a forward slash at the front it means "use the folder I'm currently in, and add this path to it".

Comment: @James - It's not really a folder.  It's .NET MVC, so I got controllers and actions.  The action that produces the page and the action that handles the AJAX call are in the same controller.  Example: 'Home/Display' is the page and 'Home/Save' is the AJAX handler.  Simply, it's a controller class Home that has 2 functions in it, Display and Save, where Display produces the page HTML and Save handles an AJAX request.

Comment: @Dimskiy - I had too much text for a comment, but I updated the text of my response, regarding relative and absolute paths.